# Apache Bigtop not building

Tags: maven, hadoop, ubuntu-14.04, oozie, bigtop

I'm following [these instruction for setting up Apache Bigtop](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/BIGTOP/Building+Bigtop+on+Ubuntu), to eventually support me running Oozie. I'm trying to use Bigtop because the Oozie website recommends the use of Bigtop if I want to run my Oozie install on Hadoop 2+.

After running the step

```
make hadoop-deb
```

I get the following error message (full message [HERE](http://pastebin.com/HcXpvt2b)):

```
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Reactor Summary: [INFO] [INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................ FAILURE [1:50.288s] [INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM ......................... SKIPPED ... ... ...
...
...
...
...
...
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:55.412s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Sep 15 14:14:17 PDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 71M/434M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:stage (default-cli) on project hadoop-main: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:stage failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:stage: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
```

Scouring the web, some people say this can be fixed by manually [deleting your /.m2 repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223536/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-compiler-plugin2-3-2comp) and then rebuilding. I've tried this to no avail.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, fully updated, with Java openjdk7. The only different between what I did and the instructions was that I have Maven installed directly from apt-get, and thus I replaced the MAVEN_HOME location the instructions use with my own.

This info might also be helpful...

```
mherbst@Oozing:~/bigtop$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_65, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-35-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Any ideas what might be the issue? I realize I'm using a slightly newer version of Ubuntu than when the guide was written, but I don't think that's the problem. This seems to be some type of Java/Maven dependency issue.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you getting your BigTop installation instructions?  I don't remember running maven as part of the install.

BigTop doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04.  There's a problem with at least one dependency (fuse-utils).  Try Ubuntu 12.02 LTS.

Comment: Literally the first sentence of my question are the instructions I'm using.

Comment: Here's what I did, worked for me.  Again, don't use Ubuntu 14.04. http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2014/01/InstallationAndConfigurationOfApacheBigtop.html

Comment: Also these steps are similar and I bet would work: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/BIGTOP/How+to+install+Hadoop+distribution+from+Bigtop+0.6.0 .. when I did it I never had to run maven, actually I don't even think I had to install maven

Comment: Alsog we spent a lot of time trying to install Oozie with Bigtop or installing it from its stand-alone tar, but in the end found support with an HDP or Cloudera solution much much better.  Bigtop is outdated with its Hadoop version

Comment: There should be a way to resolve the 14.04 dependency issue though, no? 14.04 is also the new LTS release, so it would be nice to get it working for it, which is what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the other instruction set though!

Comment: I tried to resolve the dependency.  I bet there is a way.  Let me know if you get it working :)

Comment: Stop using Ubuntu 12. It's 2015 now... Bigtop really needs to fix their build.