# How to resolve failure of dependency error?

Tags: java, maven-plugin, opendaylight, ietf-netmod-yang

This is the error I am getting while making maven build of [Open Day Light YangTools](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/YANG_Tools:Developer_Guide#Build_the_code)

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.2.1 in nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of opendaylight-mirror has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.2.1 in nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of opendaylight-mirror has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:267)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:240)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:233)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.2.1 in nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of opendaylight-mirror has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:295)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:129)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.2.1 in http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of opendaylight-mirror has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:436)
    ... 24 more
```

pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- vi: set et smarttab sw=4 tabstop=4: -->
    <!--
     Copyright (c) 2013 Cisco Systems, Inc. and others.  All rights reserved.

     This program and the accompanying materials are made available under the
     terms of the Eclipse Public License v1.0 which accompanies this distribution,
     and is available at http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html
    -->
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

        <parent>
          <groupId>org.opendaylight.odlparent</groupId>
          <artifactId>odlparent-lite</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <relativePath/>
        </parent>

        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>org.opendaylight.yangtools</groupId>
        <artifactId>yangtools-aggregator</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>yangtools</name> <!-- Used by Sonar to set project name -->
        <packaging>pom</packaging>

        <scm>
            <connection>scm:git:ssh://git.opendaylight.org:29418/yangtools.git</connection>
            <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git.opendaylight.org:29418/yangtools.git</developerConnection>
            <url>https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/YANG_Tools:Main</url>
            <tag>HEAD</tag>
        </scm>

        <modules>
            <module>common</module>
            <module>yang</module>
            <module>websocket</module>
            <module>yang-validation-tool</module>
        </modules>

        <profiles>
          <profile>
            <id>benchmarks</id>
            <activation>
              <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <modules>
              <module>benchmarks</module>
            </modules>
          </profile>

          <profile>
            <!--
                This profile is to ensure we only build javadocs reports
                when we plan to deploy Maven site for our project.
            -->
            <id>maven-site</id>
            <activation>
              <file>
                <exists>${user.dir}/deploy-site.xml</exists>
              </file>
            </activation>

            <build>
              <plugins>
                <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                  <inherited>false</inherited>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <id>aggregate</id>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <phase>package</phase>
                      <configuration>
                        <!-- ignore javadoc warnings caused by JDK8 -->
                        <additionalparam>${javadoc.args}</additionalparam>
                      </configuration>
                  </execution>
                  </executions>
                </plugin>
              </plugins>
            </build>
          </profile>
        </profiles>

        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.opendaylight.yangtools</groupId>
                                <artifactId>checkstyle-logging</artifactId>
                                <version>${project.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>

      <!--
          Maven Site Configuration

          The following configuration is necessary for maven-site-plugin to
          correctly identify the correct deployment path for OpenDaylight Maven
          sites.
      -->
      <url>${odl.site.url}/${project.groupId}/${stream}/</url>

      <distributionManagement>
        <site>
          <id>opendaylight-site</id>
          <url>${nexus.site.url}/</url>
        </site>
      </distributionManagement>
    </project>
```

while building maven build from cli using mvn clean install or mvn clean install -U.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223536/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-compiler-plugin2-3-2comp

Comment: Please check it. It solved my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223536/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-compiler-plugin2-3-2comp

Comment: I tried all the possibilities or the solution given in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223536/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-compiler-plugin2-3-2comp , But still i am getting the same error.