# Error assembling WAR - webxml attribute is required

Tags: jhipster

I'm hitting the following with a jhipster app when running the `./mvnw` build:

`Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode)`

Answer (score 2):

This regression for microservices has been reported in 4.11.0 and fixed: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/6742. New release should be available tonight.

In the meantime you can fix it in your own pom.xml by setting `failOnMissingWebXml` to false:

```
               <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
```