# Looking for solution for exporting data to Excel with Vaadin

Tags: excel, vaadin, vaadin8

We are looking for solution to export the data to excel in Vaadin application.
I have downloaded Vaadin excel exporter from GitHub https://github.com/bonprix/vaadin-excel-exporter which sounds to be a very useful utility but I am getting the error below when I am compiling vaadin-excel-exporter-demo project.

<vaadin.version>8.0.6</vaadin.version>

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project vaadin-excel-exporter-demo: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Java/Vaadin/VaadinProjetcs/vaadin-excel-exporter-master/vaadin-excel-exporter-master/vaadin-excel-exporter-demo/src/main/java/org/vaadin/addons/excelexporter/demo/DemoUI.java:[12,61] package org.vaadin.addons.excelexporter.configuration.builder does not exist

I've tried mvn clean and also delete the full .m2/repository local repository 
[Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223536/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-compiler-plugin2-3-2comp)

After searching on different forums it looks like maybe this add-on is missing from Maven repo. I have tried version 2.1 and LATEST.

```
<artifactId>vaadin-excel-exporter</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <!--version>2.1-SNAPSHOT</version-->
    <version>LATEST</version>
    <name>Excel Exporter</name>
```

So I have two questions.

1. Has anybody had the same problem wih this tool and/or  maybe can explain what i am doing wrong.
2. If this tool is not maybe available anymore can anyone please share the tool which I can use to export the grid data to Excel. I am new with Vaadin so  providing the code examples will be highly appreciated

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Have you added the `vaadin-addons` repository as per the instructions in the README?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the add-on through [Vaadin directory](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/excel-exporter), you'll find the necessary additions to your pom.xml in the Maven section of the sidebar. In this case, like Erik said in the comments, you are likely missing

```
<repository>
   <id>vaadin-addons</id>
   <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
</repository>
```

The directory page also includes code samples for using the component after you get the dependencies fixed, as well as other information about the add-on. I haven't tested whether the demo within GitHub works, but the add-on itself should be usable in your project regardless. The newest version published through the directory is 2.0.

If you want to compile the add-on locally rather than use it through the add-on repository, you need to first successfully compile the add-on module, and then use the exact version configured in the pom.xml. Currently the master branch seems to be using `<version>2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>`.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have checked pom.xml of vaadin-excel-exporter-demo project and vaadin add-on repository is there

Comment: vaadin-addons repository is in the pom.xml

Comment: Find another message in the log and wanted to share: Failed to execute goal on project vaadin-excel-exporter-demo: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.vaadin.addons:vaadin-excel-exporter-demo:war:2.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.vaadin.addons:vaadin-excel-exporter:jar:2.1-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vaadin-addons has elapsed or updates are forced

Comment: And some good news finally. I was able to run the application after running mvn clean package on the root project